# MVP Pattern : Separating the database dependency from the presenter?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, webforms, moq

Whenever I try to actually unit test a presenter and a mocked view, I end up running into too many database dependencies

```
 public EditAccount(IAccountEditPage _view, ISession _session, IResponse _response)
 {

 }

 public void view_SaveUser()
 {
   //Class that takes the view's data and persists it to DB  
 }
```

Obviously I can't write unit tests for this presenter because I have a concretion of using my model class that has a strong database dependency.

How am I supposed to removed the dependency on the database without constructor injecting every class that touches the database in my presenter?  I don't want to do this every time in every view I have.

I'm using moq, if it helps.

Edit : Also I should mention that the code in "view_SaveUser" is very lean and isn't direct database access or anything like that.  It's usually only a few lines.  I'm not overstepping the scope of the presenter, AFAIK.

Comment: Its pretty common to have a constructor dependency on your data provider. I'm not familiar with MVP, but in MVC, its standard practice have an IRepository constructor parameter. You could also use property injection via a DI container like Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to inject the instances on the constructor another option you have is using a setter injection using a IoC framework as [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/) or [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) to inject the dependencies.

Doing this, you would only need to specify on the framework configuration which classes are used for real code and for test project, dependencies would be automatically injected and you would avoid having to use the contructor.

Comment: Interesting; thanks.  Most MVP pattern examples are terse and lack his real world usage information.